# Universal Etymology of Words

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology

Where could I find examples of words and their etymologies that occur frequently in many different languages?

For example, I know that the English word "Mother" shares a similar etymology with many other languages from civilizations across the globe.

Is there an online resource that provides examples of some (or many!) other words like this.

Again, to clarify the question, have any papers or articles been posted online of a list of examples of these common words or roots?

<sup>Question copied from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59419/universal-etymology-of-words/59420#59420).</sup>

Comment: are you interested in grammatical words that have similar etymologies? for example, the etymology of a word that is used to show past tense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is a list of [cognates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate), i.e. words with a shared etymology; this way, you could try doing a more successful research by using the term.

I didn't find any papers specifically listing a lot of cognates for several different languages but you can find something here and there, such as [this list](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Transwiki%3aList_of_German_cognates_with_English) on Wiktionary.

[On the Linguist List site](http://mailman.uib.no/public/corpora/2007-January/003874.html), someone asked a similar question to yours and they gave a link to this document listing English-Spanish cognates: [Cognates](http://buildingrti.utexas.org/PDF/Cognates_sp.pdf) by [Greg Kondrak](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~kondrak/), who also wrote this about identiying cognates: "*[Identiﬁcation of Cognates and Recurrent
Sound Correspondences in Word Lists](http://atala.org/IMG/pdf/TAL-2009-50-2-08-Kondrak.pdf)"*, or *"[Clustering Semantically Equivalent Words into Cognate Sets in Multilingual List](http://aclweb.org/anthology/I/I11/I11-1097.pdf)"*. There's also [this site](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~kondrak/cognatesEF.html) listing French-English cognates.

Comment: An old analysis of how easy it is to find 'plausible' cognates in unrelated languages: http://www.zompist.com/chance.htm

Comment: i thought the question was about pathways of semantic change which recur in unrelated languages?

Comment: @jlovegren The OP asked for a paper/article that listed examples of words sharing etymologies across languages, which are cognates. I didn't read anything about what you said in your comment.

Comment: @Alenanno What made me think that was the part where it says "For example, I know that the English word "Mother" shares a similar etymology with many other languages from civilizations across the globe." The "across the globe" part made me think the OP wants to found out something about unrelated languages.

Comment: @jlovegren Isn't that still a cognate? such as "father" and "père"? As far as I know cognates aren't limited to "related languages", since for example, there are cognates between English and Romance languages, including also the Slavic family, such as the word "mother".

Comment: Romance, Slavic, and Germanic are all related at the level of Indo-European. But I guess I am now convinced that you correctly guessed the OP's intended question. Since the OP used quotes around "mother" I am guessing that the issue of interest is sound-meaning::sound-meaning correspondence between lgs, rather than meaning->meaning::meaning->meaning correspondence between lgs.

Comment: Yes, they are related at that level. :)

Comment: @jlovegren: Thanks for being more coherent than I could be in the original question.  Yes, I was hoping to track down similarities in sound-meaning, as you said, across non-related (or related) languages.  Digging a bit further even, what are the most common sound-meanings (using that term correctly?) among related languages?

Comment: @Norla Asking a question in a comment is not the best practice. Also, from your question body it seems a different question.

Comment: @Norla following the moderator's advice, why not try posting another question? You'll get better information like that.

Comment: @Norla If you need to ask a different question, you can, there is no prohibition for you to do that. I honestly interpreted your question the other way, if I felt differently I wouldn't have answered. Next time, try to be as clear and as specific as possible. It will help you get better answers!

Comment: Sure, asking new question.  Will include "cognates" and "sound-meanings" and probably "please".

Comment: The Portuguese/English list you quote isn't so much a list of false cognates as a list of false friends. The first four, for example, seem to be true cognates (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @JPP Uhm... I suppose you have a point. I'll just remove that part, it isn't that related anyway.